# How can I force a TD with no content to render its border?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fadeout, html-table

The TD has a DIV inside which I removed using jQuery's fadeOut function, but when it finishes the border disappears too.

I want to avoid that, is there any way other than adding a "&nbsp;" (which causes it to be ugly)?

EDIT: I am using Internet Explorer (6 and 7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSS:

```
table {
  empty-cells: show;
}
```

You also need to put IE in standards rendering mode for this to work. After adding a doctype, at least IE8 (Beta 2 and higher) plays nicely.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

IE7 and below still won't do it. Support for `empty-cells` is said to be "partial" (for IE7 and IE8 Beta 1) on [the MS CSS compatibility statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx). Whatever "partial" means, not implementing "show" can hardly be called "partial support". These browsers can be forced to draw the cell borders by generally collapsing table borders:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;   
}
```

The setting of `empty-cells` is ignored. But once you collapse the borders, you don't need to set that anyway, because all browsers will display collapsed borders.

Comment: @Juan: this is the correct way to do it, but it doesn't work in IE

Comment: Hm... it works for me. Are you sure the empty-cells property setting makes it to that table you hare having problems with? Maybe it's overridden somewhere?

Comment: Are you using IE? I double checked it, it seems to be correctly applied

Comment: IE seems to do it only when you collapse the borders. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: That works, however, it also stacks all cells together, ignoring the padding. +1 for the trouble though

Comment: You can do the padding within the cell. Or do you want to display double borders?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder =); I already got it working with the transparent image, but I'll try this in a bit and if it works, I'll accept this answer as it's a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> - This worked great

Answer (score 5):

Add a non-breaking space to the cell:

`<td>&nbsp;</td>`

A hack, but a better hack than adding an image.

Comment: @Andrew: didn't you read Juan's responses: he doesn't want to do this because it messes up his layout

Comment: @Christoph, gothcha. I will leave the post though.

Comment: Use &amp; to escape the ampersand in " "

Comment: Why is this upvoted? It clearly isn't useful, I pretty much say it in my question, and it's debated on Tomalak answer

Answer (score 5):

<td style="font-size: 1pt">&nbsp;<td>

Comment: This is the solution I wound up using. The font-size is to prevent the width of the nbsp from messing up the layout. I found that "font-size: 0" works in the browsers I checked.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up adding a transparent 1px image to the cell as  [suggested by Jukka "Yucca" Korpela](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML/emptycells.html). For now I'll use this solution if there is no better alternative

Comment: I think the <img> is way more ugly than the  . From a source code point of view at least. Or is it the look when the text is selected that bothers you?

Comment: Yes, it's the look... it messes up the whole table

Comment: Lots of sites use the   trick, so users are used to it.  You can improve it a little by reducing the font size to 1pt.

Comment: The 1px image creates an additional request, slowing down your page. Using   is a better solution IMO.

Comment: @Magnar, in this case, it's an intranet application, so that is not really an issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: <reminder>What about the question I asked in the comments to my answer?</reminder>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, you could set the `visibility`-property of the div to `hidden` instead of setting its `display`-property to `none`, ie you'd have to restore `display` <del>and `opacity`</del> and set `visibility` manually after the call to `fadeOut()`.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a table like below:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <td>Breakfast</td>
 <td><div id="foo">Lunch</div></td>
 <td>Dinner</td></tr>
</table>
```

And you fadeOut, with jQuery, Lunch, why not bring back a blank nothing with fadeIn?

Like below:

```
$("#foo").fadeOut("slow").html('').fadeIn("fast");
```

Comment: I though about doing something like this, but what happens when they meet in the middle? (Opacity = 0.5)? I didn't try it because I though it wouldn't look good

Comment: Could be wrong, but don't the links in the jQuery chain execute only after previous has gone to boot? And since you have some bluff in the middle, the fadeIn train shouldn't cross tracks with the fadeOut too noticeably. Tested okay on Opera 9, IE6 and FF3.

Comment: You are right about the "chainability"; I don't know if the borders will flicker between the fadeout and the fadein, I'll test it in a while (although you say you tested it...)